# UIScrollView issue with objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

Right now I have an UIScrollView, which has a lot of UIImageViews, UILabels and other objects. Now I have to be able to scroll from one storyboard view to another. I added another view to the storyboard, now how do I scroll from one view controller to the other without messing up the previous objects? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Virindh Borra

Comment: Scroll from one storyboard to another? Define your question...

Comment: Put the views underneath each other in the UIScrollView. Do you know how to use UIScrollView?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by underneath each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have to views, View1 and View2, and a UIScrollView scroller.

Assuming I understand the question, try this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    CGrect frame = self.View2.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 480; // assuming View1 and View2 has frames 320x480
    self.View2.frame = frame;
    self.scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,480*2);
}
```

Now View1's frame = [320,480], View2's frame = [320,480], scrollers content = [320,480*2] making space enough for both views.

Comment: how would I do this on iPad, with paging? and where would i put the above code?? Thanks For All Your Help!!

Comment: Simply change 480 to the ipad's height and 320 to it's width.

Comment: After I make enough space for the 2 views, I try to add a view as a subview, but it is not showing up, it just scrolls to empty space. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: You have to specify. Add what view to which subview? Are you updating your scroller?

Comment: I got it Fixed, Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Good. What did you do to fix it?